# ModuleNotFoundError when importing pydantic in a file outside of main in a Google Cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, cython, python-3.8, pydantic

I have a local langchain fork I'm trying to include in a cloud function, but am receiving a ModuleNotFoundError when one of the files in that fork tries to import pydantic while deploying the function.

This is my requirements.txt:

```
pinecone-client>=2.1.0
langchain>=0.0.63
pydantic>=1.9.1
SQLAlchemy>=1.4.40
requests>=2.28.2
numpy>=1.22.3
```

This is the line in main .py that causes the issue:

```py
from langchain_local.agents import Tool, AgentExecutor, ZeroShotAgent
```

And this is the line in agent.py (where AgentExecutor is defined) where the error occurs:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator
```

I tried including this import statement in main.py and another file in langchain_local called tools.py and found that while it did not cause any issue when included in main.py it caused the same issue in tools.py. Is there any known issue with importing pydantic in files outside of main.py in Google Cloud functions?

The relevant part of my directory structure is:

```
|langchain_local/
|---|__init__.py
|---|agents/
|---|---|__init__.py
|---|---|agent.py
|---|---|tools.py
|main.py
|requirements.txt
```

Here is the full trace:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework", line 8, in  sys.exit(_cli()) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in **call** return self.main(*args, **kwargs) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main rv = self.invoke(ctx) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke return __callback(*args, **kwargs) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py", line 37, in _cli app = create_app(target, source, signature_type) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/**init**.py", line 288, in create_app spec.loader.exec_module(source_module) File "", line 843, in exec_module File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/workspace/main.py", line 1, in  from langchain_local.agents import Tool, AgentExecutor, ZeroShotAgent File "/workspace/langchain_local/**init**.py", line 5, in  from langchain_local.agents import MRKLChain, ReActChain, SelfAskWithSearchChain File "/workspace/langchain_local/agents/**init**.py", line 2, in  from langchain_local.agents.agent import Agent, AgentExecutor File "/workspace/langchain_local/agents/agent.py", line 8, in  from langchain_local.agents.tools import Tool File "/workspace/langchain_local/agents/tools.py", line 4, in  from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic'

Comment: Can you share with us the full error message. Also have a look at this [Github Link](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1136) which suggests to define `pydantic` models outside the root `main.py` file and import them from there.

Comment: The pydantic model is defined outside of main.py in the agent.py file